# Why is everything adaptive with a normal screen reduction? and when switching to the mobile version, the size 980x2359 is included?

Tags: html, css

There is such an authorization code, when the page is reduced in the preview, everything is fine and beautiful, but if you go from a mobile device, we see a very large resolution, and everything is very small

```css
<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
    width: 360px;
    padding: 8% 0 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.form {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    padding: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    outline: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: 0;
    background: #4CAF50;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
    transition: all 0.3 ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
    background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    color: #b3b3b3;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
    color: #4CAF50;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
    display: none;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.container .info {
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
    color: #4d4d4d;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
    color: #EF3B3A;
}
body {
    background: #76b852; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #7e8794, #8DC26F);
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.fail{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: red;
    margin: 10px;
}

.form input#reg {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: 0;
    background: #4CAF50;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
    transition: all 0.3 ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.form input#reg:hover,.form input#reg:active,.form input#reg:focus {
    background: #43A047;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html><head>
    <title>Авторизация </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body><div class="login-page">

    <div class="form">
        <form class="login-form" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль">
            <div class="fail"></div>
            <button name="submit" type="submit">Войти</button>
            <input id="reg" type="button" onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" value="Регистрация (Telegram)">


        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

I can’t publish any details, but I have already described them all, please help, who knows the solution to the problem, I will be grateful

Comment: Why you use `<script>` instead of `<style>` for inline css?

Comment: I apologize when publishing, I deleted an unnecessary piece of code and accidentally copied not a style, but a script

Comment: Have you tried adding [`<meta name="viewport" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name#standard_metadata_names_defined_in_other_specifications) to your `<head>`?

Comment: Thank you, it worked)